# Django: how to create a dictionary of objects and display in templates

Tags: python, django, dictionary, templates

Hey I have had a look at similar questions but none really relate to what I am trying to do, they either explain how to order things in the admin panel or simply iterating over object dictionaries.

I have created a basic photo model that contains a value gallery_order so I can edit them in Admin.

I wish to populate my template with the pictures according to the gallery_order values in order from 1 upward.

I guess the best way to handle it is with a dictionary but I do not know where to initialize it, if I put it in the picture model then each picture holds a dict with all the pictures order number and url in it which seems mental.

My current model:

```
class Picture(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=36, blank=False, unique=True)
    gallery_order = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/', blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

My template code:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    {% block content %}
    <div class="row">
        {% if pictures %}
            {% for picture in pictures %}
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="card mb-0">
                        <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ picture.image.url }}">
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    </div>
    {% endblock content %}
</head>
```

my admin code:

```
@admin.register(Picture)
class PictureAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('gallery_order', 'title', 'image')
    list_display_links = ['gallery_order']
    search_fields = ['title']

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        queryset = super(PictureAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        queryset = queryset.order_by('gallery_order')
        return queryset
```

I tried to figure out how django was displaying them by looking at the PK in psotgres db but it seems to simply display them according to last edited.

Thank You :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also do this at the model level by adding the following at the end of your model.

```
class Meta:
        ordering = ['gallery_order']
```

Answer (score 0):

I am so silly sometimes I forgot about my views!

all I had to do was specify order_by for goodness sake...

```
class Home(View):

    pictures = Picture.objects.all().order_by('gallery_order')

    def get(self, request):
        return render(request, 'home.html', {'pictures': self.pictures})
```